# Graphical circuit simulator like Logisim

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, cpu

I wanted to make a CPU and then somehow measure its efficiency/speed.

Logisim is a little buggy, and I don't think it allows you to do any sort of testing/measurement. Does a tool like this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a complex project such as this, you would be better to use an HDL like Verilog or VHDL and a simulator.

There are open source Verilog tools available like [Icarus](http://iverilog.icarus.com/). Also since all the major FPGA vendors have a free version of their dev tools, you could just download and use these.
For example the free version of Xilinx ISE has HDL and schematic entry capabilites, an excellent simulation tool. Actel's (now Microsemi) Libero IDE comes with similar HDL/schematic entry and Modelsim for simulation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using electra.academy to simulate a CPU (Ben Eater's version) and it is running well.

You can step run or by using the provided clock. Checking signals and opcodes cycles is ok. Checking "real" performance not.

https://electra.academy/simulator/?shared=7736858c77175aa639676e7b4669f0655f0bc727

MAybe this tool fits your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout CircuitVerse - Digital Circuit Simulator which is extremely easy to use but still powerful. It has full support for multibit wires and subcircuits. My college uses this in our courses.

https://circuitverse.org/