# Custom-CPU builder/simulator

Tags: cpu, programmable-logic, c++, alu, gpu

I googled deeply but couldn't find any **cpu constructor simulator**.
I'm specifically hoping to learn about the operation of the northbridge, but When I googled "bridge simulator" or "bridge (the construction game)" is the result.

I don't want to simulate existing architectures. İ need to create my own.

**Question:** Do you know any free project (ideally C++) with this flexibility:

- Place ALUs, FPUs, etc arbitrarily
- Make the instruction fetcher width 8 bytes
- Allows operation with an arbitrary set of components (E.G, build a system that doesn't utilize L2/L3 cache)
- Designate instruction pipeline length
- Run the simulated hardware at various frequencies
- Can simulate a GPU (or GPUs)

Is there a utility that would allow me to experiment with hardware design in a click-and-drag CAD manner? If there isn't, how complicated would it be to make such a simulator for 8-bit systems?

Comment: I answered a [similar question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37588/graphical-circuit-simulator-like-logisim?rq=1) a little while ago, have a read and see if it helps at all.

Comment: You want to learn an HDL (Hardware Description Language), like **VHDL** or **Verilog**. FPGA vendors have development tools for their products, often free up to a certain level, which includes simulation. Doing this in C++ is next to insane.

Comment: Okay, looking to these sources and questions

Comment: Trying to register verilog now

Comment: "northbridge" is a component of a specific system architecture which would likely be irrelevant to a custom CPU.  You will likely have more luck starting small with a simple, unoptimized design.  First write something in C or your favorite language which simulates the instruction set and which you can later use as a verification check, then implement it in an HDL such as Verilog or VHDL.

Comment: @tuğrul - "Trying to register verilog now". Don't tell us everything you do. This isn't twitter!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your question, I believe writing a simulator for 8-bit systems would be over your head.